# hash function behaves different with empty vector in clojure and clojurescript

Tags: hash, clojure, clojurescript

These days, I was trying to utilize function hash in clojure/clojurescript to generate unique id, but it turns out this function has very strange behaviour to empty vector parsed from `read-string` in cljs with in clj.

In clojure, hash function return `-2017569654` for empty vector and the one parsed from `read-string`

```
user=> (hash [])
-2017569654
user=> (hash (read-string "[]"))
-2017569654
```

However, in cljs, `(hash [])` returns surprisingly 0. And `[]` are also equal to `(read-string "[]")`.

```
cljs.user=> (hash (cljs.reader/read-string "[]"))
-2017569654

cljs.user=> (hash [])
0

cljs.user=> (= [] (cljs.reader/read-string "[]"))
true
```

Does any one know the reason of it and how to solve it in cljs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is [a bug in ClojureScript](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-962).

```
homepage.core> [(hash [2]) (hash (cljs.reader/read-string "[2]"))]
[-1917711765 -1917711765]
homepage.core> [(hash [0]) (hash (cljs.reader/read-string "[0]"))]
[965192274 965192274]
homepage.core> [(hash []) (hash (cljs.reader/read-string "[]"))]
[0 -2017569654]
homepage.core> [(hash {}) (hash (cljs.reader/read-string "{}"))]
[-15128758 -15128758]
homepage.core> [(hash #{}) (hash (cljs.reader/read-string "#{}"))]
[0 0]
homepage.core> *clojurescript-version*
"0.0-2496"
```

When compared to the other types, the hashing of `[]` looks a bit off.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! It seems I have to think of other way before this bug is fixed.

Comment: ClojureScript has a fairly fast release cycle, it shouldn't be too long.

Comment: looks like the patch is in, so this is likely to be resolved soon.

Comment: fixed. it will go out in the next release.